# JavaFx Fill WidthColumn Constraint is not working inside a layout

Tags: java, javafx

I’m going to add two text fields in a row of Java FX GridPane layout. And I want to fill one text field throughout the available space. If I add GridPane directly to the Scene, then it is working fine. But If I add GridPane to another layout like Group (or any other layout) then fill property is not working correctly.

Following code is working as expected.

```
public void start(final Stage stage) {
    GridPane parent = new GridPane();
    TextField addEmail = new TextField();
    TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
    parent.add(addEmail, 0, 0);
    parent.add(addFirstName, 1, 0);

    ColumnConstraints cons1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    cons1.setFillWidth(true);
    cons1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

    parent.getColumnConstraints().add(cons1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 400, 300, Color.WHITE);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

[image]

Following one is not working (But I want to make this work).

```
public void start(final Stage stage) {
        GridPane parent = new GridPane();
        TextField addEmail = new TextField();
        TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
        parent.add(addEmail, 0, 0);
        parent.add(addFirstName, 1, 0);

        ColumnConstraints cons1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        cons1.setFillWidth(true);
        cons1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        parent.getColumnConstraints().add(cons1);

        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().addAll(parent);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 300, Color.WHITE);        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

[image]

I’m new to Java FX hence my approach may completely wrong please direct me to the correct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you've chosen the wrong parent.

From [the javadoc of `Group`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html)

> By default, a `Group` will ***"auto-size"*** its managed resizable children ***to their preferred sizes*** during the layout pass to ensure that `Region`s and `Control`s are sized properly as their state changes.

A `Group` simply does not modify the size of it's children other than resizing them to the preferred size.

Only if you put the `GridPane` in a parent that resizes it, like e.g. `StackPane`, it's size is modified...

Comment: Oh thank you fabian, I tried with anchorpane and scroll pane as well. According to your answer, same thing will apply for those layout as well right?

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna Totally depends on the layout parameters, e.g. try `AnchorPane` with the right and left anchors set for the `GridPane` or a `ScrollPane` with `fitToWidth`= `true`

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabian for helping. FitToWidth is working nicely for ScrollPane. You save my day!